# How to update billing_email in Woocommerce (if empty)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Email address not mandatory on our checkout page.

We want to update `billing_email` to our custom email if the customer does not provide an email.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'set_email_for_guest');
function set_email_for_guest( $order_id ) {
    $email = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_email', true );
    if(empty($email)){
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', 'example@example.com' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the hook that you should use is *not* `woocommerce_thankyou`. Instead, you should choose from one of the following hooks which both worked for me in WordPress 5.6.1 with WooCommerce 5.0.0 (which are both the latest releases as of writing):

And note that these hooks pass `$data` as the second parameter which is an array of the POST-ed/submitted (and processed) form data. However, the first parameter is a `WC_Order` instance and an order ID, respectively.

### Option 1: Use `woocommerce_checkout_create_order`

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'set_email_for_guest', 10, 2 );
function set_email_for_guest( $order, $data ) { // first param is a WC_Order instance
    if ( empty( $data['billing_email'] ) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_billing_email', 'foo@example.com' );
    }
}
```

### Option 2: Use `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'set_email_for_guest', 10, 2 );
function set_email_for_guest( $order_id, $data ) { // first param is an order/post ID
    if ( empty( $data['billing_email'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', 'foo@example.com' );
    }
}
```

So just choose whichever hook you prefer, but the first one above runs first.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the meta key:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'set_email_for_guest' );
function set_email_for_guest( $order_id ) {
    $email = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', true ); // '_billing_email' instead 'billing_email'

    if( empty( $email ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', 'example@example.com' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I test that also, not work, unfortunately.

Comment: wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'billing_email' => $user_email ) ) This maybe you are looking.?

Comment: @mujuonly I don't want to update the user profile, I just want to put the email address for the orders that the user doesn't provide an email. sometimes user is guest

Answer (score -1):

You want to update `billing_email` to custom email if the user does not provide a billing email on checkout.

So it would be a possible solution to the problem to give the email field on your checkout page a default value. This default value can be the customer email if logged in, or as in your example a hard coded value. This way you will always have a value in this field.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'set_billing_email_default_value' );
 
function set_billing_email_default_value($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['default'] = 'example@example.com';
    return $fields;
}
```

Addition:

If you want to make it read only, so the user can not edit the default value, you can set this in the fields custom attributes.

```
$fields['billing']['billing_email']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rank. But with your solution customer can remove/change the default value. I looking for a way that the user can't change/remove the value.

Comment: You can make the field read only, I edited my answer. Hope it helps